# Problemas con Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

hace un tiempo tuve que actualizar Android Studio, porque la versión que tenía en clase era más actual que la que tengo en casa y había incompatibilidades, el caso es que todo se me fue a la mierda... Más o menos, conseguí solucionarlo, pero cuando cojo un proyecto antiguo e intento crear nuevas activities, me da los siguientes errores:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\briam\Documents\AndroidStudioProjects\pruebaP\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 16s

Otro mensaje es este:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

¿Alguien me puede ayudar? Es que no puedo hacer nada ahora... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que nada asegurate de tener instalado el sdk 11.

Despues en android studio pesiona `ctrl + alt + shift + s` para abrir las propiedades del proyecto y en la seccion de proyecto elegir el sdk 11 que previamente instalaste al igual que poner el nivel del lenguaje en la version 11 si te da la opcion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tambien presiona `ctrl + alt + s` para revisar las propiedades de android studio y asegurarte que en `Build, Excution, Development>Compiler>Java Compiler` se este utilizando la version 11

Comment: Hola @Edgar Agustn Martinez Gonzalez, gracias por responder. Efectívamente, tengo instalado el SDK11, pero en project structure no me aparece como a tí...  (imágen 1 : https://www.imagenes-temporales.com/subidas/ver/2knjBM/) (así es como me aparece project structure a mí: https://www.imagenes-temporales.com/subidas/ver/9rxqMJ/)  Sin embargo sí que he seleccionado el SDK11 y ahora me aparece el siguiente error: Invalid Gradle JDK configuration found. Open Gradle Settings 
Use JDK from project structure

Comment: Funciona, gracias, ahora me va. Gracias, en serio